# Having a hard time importing Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, github

[image: This in my problem because I don't have any library project to add as reference]I Downloaded a Facebook SDK in this link https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk and I extract it. The name of the folder was "facebook-android-sdk-master" I'm tying to import the file in this way.

```
1.Project>import>Existing Project into Workspace> the file
2.Project>import>Archive File> the file
3.Project>import>File System> the file
```

and the problem was, when I'm trying to add it on my library there is nothing to add.

So I'm thinking that maybe I Downloaded a wrong Facebook SDK in github

the way that I Download the Facebook SDK was

I Clicked the ZIP Button with the Hover Text "Download this repository as zip file"

I already read a lot of tutorial about this and I just followed their exact way.

Can anyone have some clue about this problem?
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

From this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/

"Open Eclipse and create a new Android Project (File | New | Project | Android Project) for the Facebook Android SDK source and later reference it from your app. Get the content by selecting Create project from existing source and specifying the facebook directory from your git repository (~/facebook-android-sdk/facebook)."

You may also want to check out the Android beta SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/android/

Answer (score 0):

If you're including the Facebook Android Source, then you need to include it into your project. Another way to handle this would be to take the Facebook Jar file and then add it to your dependencies list.

Comment: do you have any link to download that jar. Because in the file that I downloaded in github goes not have any facebook jar. By the way thanks for the answer

Comment: Download the sdk file and iimport it into eclipse. Once imported file -> export -> click the facebook directory in the facebook sdk directory and create the jar file from that directory only.

Comment: I' Already got a Facebook Jar then Why I still can't import the Type Facebook in my Android Java.class